# How to get pivot points of RREF matrix

Tags: matlab, math, matrix, linear-algebra

I have this Reduced Row Echelon Form (RREF) matrix:

```
 1    -2     0     1     1
 0     0     1     0    -1
 0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0
```

Is there a way to get the pivot points in Matlab? I know that it will be columns 1 and 3, but I am not sure how I can do this in Matlab.

Answer (score 0):

For a Reduced Row Echelon Form matrix;

> The first non-zero entry in any row is the number 1, these are called pivots <sup>(1)</sup>

If you assume that your matrix is already in RREF then we don't care about what each value is, only if it is `0` or not, so for some RREF matrix `A`:

```
A = logical(A);
```

Then we can find the first element in each row which is non-zero using `max`

```
[v,col] = max(A,[],2);
```

Finally we can remove values from `col` where `v=0`, i.e. rows which are entirely `0`, leaving the pivots `piv`:

```
piv = col( v > 0 );
```

For your example, this returns `col = [1; 3]`

You could do this in one line, but it's not pretty

```
[~,piv] = max( logical(A(any(A,2),:)), [], 2 );
```

<sup>(1): [https://www.math.fsu.edu/~bellenot/class/f08/lalab/other/rref2.pdf](https://www.math.fsu.edu/%7Ebellenot/class/f08/lalab/other/rref2.pdf)</sup>